# jQuery trigger performance

Tags: jquery, event-handling, event-bubbling, jquery-trigger, jquery-triggerhandler

I have a performance issue with jquery trigger.
My code contains this line

```
$(ispan).trigger('click','itoc'); //ispan is a img element
```

Here the total time taken to execute this line of code is almost 3 seconds.
`ispan` is only one element. I have done some research that the trigger is doing event bubbling up the DOM tree which might consume this much time. 
How can I prevent the event bubbling. or is there any way that I can improve the performance of this trigger.  any help wld be highly appreciated.

Comment: inside click event handler put this line as first `event.stopPropagation();` and `event` must be an argument to function

Comment: I have tried that. still same time profiles.. I wonder how triggering click takes so long time

Comment: Did you try `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`?

Comment: is there any network call in click event handler?

Comment: is it possible that you accidentally defined a circular reference?

Comment: Thank you guys. this is my first question . I cud not vote up your comments now. now the event handler is the culprit it seems. the unbind click am doing inside it is using css selector which contains 8000 elements. How to optimize the jquery unbind. ? any alternative or workaround